# Stanford CoreNLP properties File not found

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do sentiment analysis on tweets but getting strange Exception.

I am initializing pipeline with properties file and place properties file in resources directory, within src->main folder.
[image]

But still getting Exception in init function :

```
Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException:    java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL
at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar.loadModel(ParserGrammar.java:188)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.loadModel(ParserAnnotator.java:212)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ParserAnnotator.<init>(ParserAnnotator.java:115)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.parse(AnnotatorImplementations.java:150)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$11.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:463)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:139)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:135)
at com.mycompany.sentmentanalysisontweets.NLP.init(NLP.java:27)
at com.mycompany.sentmentanalysisontweets.WhatToThink.main(WhatToThink.java:15)
```

In main method i'm calling `init()` method.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NLP.init();
    }
}

class NLP {
    static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

    public static void init() {
        InputStream input = NLP.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/example.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
          prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(prop);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should place your `properties` file inside your `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: i have tried this, but still does'nt working.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the following structure:

```
src/main/resources
             |
              - example.properties
```

Executing the code below will solve your problem:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NLP.init();
    }
}

class NLP {
   static StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

   public static void init() {
        InputStream input = NLP.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/example.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try {
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(prop);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Your pom.xml must contain the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <classifier>models</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: it is giving Exception:  Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz" as class path

Comment: Your code is working right, but on line shown below debugger shows exception.. "pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(prop);"

Comment: What's the exception thrown? Do you mind update your question with your edits?

Comment: @ariberio i edited the question and exception updated.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar, you're missing the `stanford-corenlp-X.X.X-models.jar` in your `classpath`. You can find the current version [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-models-current.jar) or you can browse it directly, by version, on [Maven's Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C11864822).

Comment: It worked. thanks alot @ariberio for being so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("./", "example.properties"));
```

instead of

```
            InputStream input = StanfordCoreNLP.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/example.properties");
```

will resolve the problem